# Stream audio from android to Windows 10 using USB Connections

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, audio, streaming

I'm currently finding a way how to stream or send the audio that android plays to a windows 10 computer without using any wireless techniques to avoid wireless congestions. Is there any? By the way, my phone's android version is 6.0.1

Comment: What about a connecting an audio cable from the Android headphone connection to the PC audio input? Using this there will be no wireless interference. If you want it digital you may need some handicraft work, e.g. if your phone supports headphones via USB you could use an USB audio to I2S converter and then connect the I2S to an Raspberry.

Comment: Alternativly it may also be possible with software. Some screen recorders allow to record the "Internal audio" - hence if there are tools that can record it it should be possible to send the audio data instead directly via TCP to a different program on a PC. Via adb tcp forwarding you can use the USB connection to transmit the TCP stream through the USB wire to the PC, where a program could send the audio data to the audio system. Unfortunately I don't know an app for Android that can record the internal audio and send it via TCP to an IP address.

Comment: @Robert I guess your first comment will be the best pick. But I'll be trying your second comment. I should search something easier since I'll be teaching my friends on how adb tcp works. It will be a very difficult for them since they didn't know TCP and even the basics of ADB or how to use them in advanced manners.